# How to add a conditional to show in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a task.
Show a different field depends of my object parameters.

For example for my form if message_type of current object = 'custom'
I will show one inputs if not - another.

Here is a code what works now:

```js
  form do |f|
    if f.object.new_record? || f.object.message_type == 'custom'
    f.inputs do
        f.input :custom_topic
        f.input :custom_content, as: :text
      end
    f.actions
    end
  end
```

But for show I do not know how to check it. What I have now:

```js
  show do
    attributes_table do
      if :message_type == 'custom'
        row :message_type
        row(:topic) { |object| object.notification_data['topic'] }
        row(:content) { |object| object.notification_data['content'] }
      else
        row :message_type
        row :notification_data
       end
    end
  end
```

When I run debugger it shows me

message_type={Symbol}

and I'm agree)

But how to check value of message_type for current object?

My all code bellow:

```js
ActiveAdmin.register Notification do
  belongs_to :case, finder: :find_by_slug
  permit_params :message_type, :custom_topic, :custom_content, :notification_data

  form do |f|
    if f.object.new_record? || f.object.message_type == 'custom'
    f.inputs do
        f.input :custom_topic
        f.input :custom_content, as: :text
      end
    f.actions
    end
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      if :message_type == 'custom'
        row :message_type
        row(:topic) { |object| object.notification_data['topic'] }
        row(:content) { |object| object.notification_data['content'] }
      else
        row :message_type
        row :notification_data
       end
    end
  end

  config.filters = false
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `show` block the current resource is available as a method usually named after the model you're managing. In this particular case it's probably `notification`, so the following might work:

```
  show do
    attributes_table do
      if notification.message_type == 'custom'
        row :message_type
        row(:topic) { |object| object.notification_data['topic'] }
        row(:content) { |object| object.notification_data['content'] }
      else
        row :message_type
        row :notification_data
       end
    end
  end
```